# A value of type cannot be used to initialize an entity of type

Tags: c++, c, stdcall

I have a function:

```
long __stdcall call_DLL(long n, byte s0, byte s1, long(__stdcall *CallBack)(long m, byte s0, byte s1)){
//trying to copy the address of CallBack to another pointer
long *x = &CallBack;
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
a value of type "long(__stdcall *CallBack)(long m, byte s0, byte 
s1)"cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "long *"
```

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to copy a function pointer into a `long*`?

Comment: You're trying to assign a pointer of type long; with a pointer of a function.  I can't do it captain! I don't have the Type!

Comment: You are trying to assign a pointer to a function, to a pointer to a `long`. These types are simply not compatible. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: this is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suppose, the question you actually wanted to ask is "How do I store the pointer to the callback?", your current "problem" cannot be solved

Comment: Anyone knows how you can do WHAT? If you want to assign `a pointer to a function` value to a variable which is `a pointer to long int` then the answer has already been given by your compiler: you _can't_. But if you want to do something else, please specify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? You shouldn't have both tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to save the callback to use it later, you can do:

```
long (* __stdcall x)(long, byte, byte) = CallBack;
```

or in C++ you can also use `auto` for brevity:

```
auto x = CallBack;
```

In either case, use it later like

```
long ret = x(n, s0, s1);
```

Otherwise, if you want to just call that CallBack, do something like

```
long x = CallBack(n, s0, s1);
```

Comment: if OP really needs to store the pointer then `auto` wont help, no? Or is something like  `static auto x = &Callback;` allowed?

Comment: The question is tagged both C and C++ (it should be one or the other). If the OP is using a C compiler, `auto` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than initialize a function pointer with an incompatible  `long *`,  initialize it with a compatible type. [@Algirdas Preidžius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752011/a-value-of-type-cannot-be-used-to-initialize-an-entity-of-type/48753269#comment84504662_48752011)

[pointer to function (long, byte, byte) returning long](https://cdecl.org/?q=long+%28*x%29%28long%2C+byte%2C+byte%29).

```
long __stdcall call_DLL(long n, byte s0, byte s1,
    long (__stdcall *CallBack)(long m, byte s0, byte s1)) {

  // long *x = &CallBack;
  long (__stdcall *x)(long, byte, byte) = CallBack;

  // sample usage of `x`
  return x(n, s0, s1);
}
```